# How to fix broken GPT, GUID and unmountable and without type volumes?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mount, efi, guid

I have Macbook pro with mavericks and 512GB SSD i accidentally deleted a partition and suddenly my mac could not boot any more and after i tried to do something with disk utility this is `gpt -r show disk0` command output:

```
    start        size  index  contents
        0           1          PMBR
        1           1          Pri GPT header
        2          32          Pri GPT table
       34      409606          
   409640   823778456       1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
824188096     1269536       2  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
825457632    24695840     
850153472   126951424       3  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B    
977104896         131
977105027          32          Sec GPT table
977105059           1          Sec GPT header
```

So i followed the soultion on [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/how-to-fix-broken-efi-partition) and do this command  `sudo gpt remove -i 1 disk0` then i countinued with this command:

```
sudo gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
```

and the `gpt -r show disk0` command output become like this:

```
    start        size  index  contents
        0           1          PMBR
        1           1          Pri GPT header
        2          32          Pri GPT table
       34           6
       40      409600       1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640   823778456      
824188096     1269536       2  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
825457632    24695840     
850153472   126951424       3  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B    
977104896         131
977105027          32          Sec GPT table
977105059           1          Sec GPT header
```

and i realized i deleted Macintosh HD volume index so i kept manipulating the table until the `gpt -r show disk0` command output  becomes like this

```
    start       size  index   contents
        0          1          PMBR
        1          1          Pri GPT header
        2         32          Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600       1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  823778456       2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
824188096    1269536       3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC     
825457632  151647395
977105027          32          Sec GPT table
977105059           1          Sec GPT header
```

but still have the same problem here i did this command `dd if=/dev/disk0s2 of=/Volumes/APP/Mac.iso` to backup this volume in external HDD and i tried to open this iso with peazip in windows vista but i can not see nothing inside did i backup my data with the command i mentioned? and how can i get the data out of Mac.iso file?

then i tried this command `newfs_msdos -v EFI /dev/disk0s1`  and suddenly the SDD turns to MBR and no volumes there, so i used command to create gpt table and this was successfully done and i make the changes to go to the original table also i play with disk utility and this is my current situation:

`diskutil list disk0` command output:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         421.8 GB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_Boot                         650.0 MB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Untitled 2              12.5 GB    disk0s3
   4:                        EFI                         65.0 GB    disk0s4
```

and this is `gpt -r show disk0` output:

```
    start        size  index  contents
        0           1          PMBR
        1           1          Pri GPT header
        2          32          Pri GPT table
       34      409606          
   409640   823778456       1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
824188096     1269536       2  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
825457632    24433696       3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
849891328      262144
850153472   126951424       4  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B    
977104896         131
977105027          32          Sec GPT table
977105059           1          Sec GPT header
```

Now, the Macintosh HD volume shows in disk utility as disk0s1 and it is not mountable and also i tried linux live cd and gparted (disk management application) could not recognize volumes types accept for Untitled 2 volume that i created with disk utility not by using commands.

Please help me in fixing my problem to enter OS X and my data or in mounting Macintosh HD volume and put volumes types without format because i want to backup my data before re-install OS X.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it easier to reinstall the os?

Comment: I have to backup my data first and i can not reinstall witjout format becuase of what i posted on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a spare linux box you can try to use [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org) to mount and possibly recover the data on your Mac (hfs+) partitions.

- [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org)

The SystemRescueCD contains TestDisk which I have used to recover data from Linux, Windows as well as Mac file systems:

- [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

I think there is also a TestDisk Mac app you can install and run from a Mac OS computer, so as long as you can mount your bad drive you can use TaskDisk to try to receover the data. But I have not tried this so you might have to test it out first on a dummy drive before working on your real drive.

Comment: Yes i used SystemRescueCd and used gparted app inside the cd the problem is that volume is unrecognized. Gparted says it unknown filesystem. How can i mount the volume as hfs+ without formating. Thank you.

Comment: Did you use TestDisk? It can scan the sectors and try to locate the superblocks and guess at the file information. If you've lost the superblock info, that's the only way to recover the data (the normal disk partitioners won't help you there).

Comment: I have no good experience with TestDisk but i did this:
TestDisk>Advanced>Superblocks
and this the output
Volume header (Bad)
Backup volume header (Bad)
Sectors are identical.
Is that what i should do?

Comment: Yes, go through the prompts and give it the best info you know or can guess at so it can try to decipher the type of file system it's looking for. It will go through the sectors and try to identify the superblocks and reconstruct the partition table. I would assume your choice is just to select "Mac" for the partition table type. See this page from the docs: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step