# Accidentally Removed EFI Partition

Tags: disk-utility, partition, efi

I removed the EFI partition accidentally but I have it on a Time machine backup. Is there a way to simply move it from my external drive to my boot drive.

[image]

I've tried restoring the format of the boot drive EFI but it gives me an error.

bash-3.2# diskutil eraseVolume fat32 EFI disk0s1
Started erase on disk0s1
Unmounting disk
Error: -5344: MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation

Any help will be awesomely appreciated.

Comment: So we learn how did you mange to erase it,could you tell us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix broken EFI partition?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/how-to-fix-broken-efi-partition)

Comment: I'm actually not sure I was getting rid of a recovery partition and I think I muddles the disk identifier. So I used the zeroDisk command and then the eraseVolume one. That have me a partition that was hfs+ and I tried changing it back to fat32 as above but that didn't work. I copied the Bootlog from the old EFI partition to my desktop. Is there a way to format it properly and I can probably just copy that file over. Im still logged into the mac so if I shut down it's not going to work

Comment: Thanks for that Buscar but that won't do it for me as I'm stuck on this machine at the minute and I can't unmount the drive. 

Does anyone know of anyway other that 'gpt' to change the format of the hfs+ to efi, alternatively - is there a way to swap these out as I have that partition on the external ? Essentially I just need to swap out disk0s1 with disk1s1

Comment: here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237  and here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4125