# How to fix the error: "This disk doesn’t contain an EFI system partition"?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

I get the following error and cannot start Bootcamp after accidentally deleting the EFI-partition of my main drive.

> This disk doesn’t contain an EFI system partition.
>   If you want to start up your computer with this disk or include it in a RAID set, back up your data and partition this disk.

Here is my `diskutil list` result :

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macbook Pro            *498.9 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 A6AC962B-74A5-42E8-B84D-B5A7A6325432
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *154.1 MB   disk3
   1:     Apple_partition_scheme                         134.2 MB   disk3s0
   2:        Apple_partition_map                         1.0 KB     disk3s0s1
   3:                  Apple_HFS BOLT! 4G E5372s         8.5 MB     disk3s0s2
```

And here is my `sudo gpt -r show disk0` result :

```
start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     409640  975093952      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  975503592    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976773128          7         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

The currently installed OS is Yosemite.

How do I fix that error?

Comment: There is a answer in your question already. Restore your disk. You still have the EFI on the disk but it might be broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the EFI System Partition (ESP) using the command-line tool gpt.
Since you have to modify your current start device you need to boot to Internet Recovery Mode or an external (thumb) drive.

Additionally you need a valid EFI-partition or an image file of it.

Here is a similar question: [How to fix broken EFI partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/how-to-fix-broken-efi-partition). I have copied some of the steps of the accepted answer. Check all the warnings there before proceeding. So please credit the OP.

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive).
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (Mavericks or Yosemite) or a thumb drive containing a full system (Mavericks or Yosemite). The disk identifiers may be different then.

**Rebuild the EFI-partition:**

First you should get an overview of your disks and the partition layout:

- Enter `diskutil list`
  Example listing:

  ```
  /dev/disk0
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
     1:                  Apple_HFS                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
     2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.2 GB   disk0s2
     3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
  /dev/disk1
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:     Apple_partition_scheme                         *1.3 GB    disk1
     1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk1s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        *1.3 GB    disk1s2
  /dev/disk2
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:                  Apple_HFS Macbook Pro            *498.9 GB   disk2
                               Logical Volume on disk0s2
                               A6AC962B-74A5-42E8-B84D-B5A7A6325432
                               Unlocked Encrypted
  /dev/disk3-disk12 ...belong to the OS X Base System (your recovery system you booted to previously)
  ```

  Disk0 is your main internal disk device containing the EFI-partition (dis0s1), the CoreStorage partition (disk0s2) and the Recovery HD (disk0s3).

  Disk1 is a logical disk created by booting to the netboot image which contains a recovery system (OS X Base System = disk1s2) similar to the Recovery HD.

  Disk2 is also a logical disk residing in disk0s2 and it contains the CoreStorage stack.
- Enter `sudo gpt -r show disk0`
  Example listing:

  ```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     409640  975093952      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  975503592    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  976773128          7         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
  ```

  The partition with the index number 1 is the wrong formatted EFI-partition, the partition with index number 2 is your CoreStorage partition and the partition with index number 3 is your Recovery HD.
  The correct GUID for the EFI-partition is C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B.
- To manipulate the GPT you have to unmount all mounted volumes on disk0 (first the CoreStorage volume, which has its own disk identifier disk2 but resides on disk0, then disk0):

  ```
  diskutil unmountDisk disk2
  diskutil unmountDisk disk0
  ```
- To delete your wrong EFI-partition enter:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 1 disk0
  ```
- Now re-add the EFI-partition with the correct layout and type

  ```
  gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
  ```
- Enter `exit` and quit Terminal.
- Reboot to your main volume

  This should sort out the partition itself, but as you've created an HFS partition in its place, you need to fix its format as well.
- The format of the [EFI System Partition is documented by Apple here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2166/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003927-CH1-SUBSECTION6). As you can see, they recommend you clone an existing ESP rather than recreating the file system with `newfs_msdos`. If you have an external drive with a GPT partition table (OSX install stick should have it), you can clone that.

  **Make sure you have your disk and partition numbers the right way around or you may overwrite data:**

  If disk1 is your external drive, and it contains an ESP as the first partition (disk1s1) and disk0 is the drive whose ESP (disk0s1) you want to fix, run this command:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/disk1s1 of=/dev/disk0s1
  ```

  you have to enter an admin password.

  This will copy every single block of disk1's ESP and overwrite the corresponding block in disk0's ESP with it.

  Alternatively, take a gamble with `newfs_msdos`.