# EFI Partition seems to have been replaced, can still boot with rEFInd but need to repair EFI Partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, partition, efi

Somehow in the process of installing Ubuntu on an external drive I seem to have overwritten my EFI partition to an HFS+ format named "Ubuntu". With rEFInd installed I don't have any problems booting into macOS, so I'm wondering if there is a non-destructive way of rebuilding my EFI partition.

```
diskutil list
```

gives me:

[image: diskutil list]

where /dev/disk0s1 should be the EFI partition that is missing. Does anybody have any tips on how to non-destructively rebuild the EFI partition?

Comment: With a similar problem, I used this to change the partition type to EFI: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342139/14586

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody has the same problem in the future, I solved it by following these instructions
[How to fix broken EFI partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57597/how-to-fix-broken-efi-partition)

Comment: If you've installed rEFInd to the "EFI" partition, applying the accepted answer will break it! You either backup the content of the 200 MiB "Ubuntu"  partition and restore it after "repartitioning" the main drive or you have to reinstall rEFInd!

Comment: I had to reinstall rEFInd after fixing the EFI partition but macOS defaults back to BOOT. A quick reinstall of rEFInd and I was back where I needed to be.