# High Sierra won't install: for the boot disk it says: "This disk cannot be used to start your computer"

Tags: hard-drive, macos, startup, ssd, high-sierra

I have a macbook pro late 2012, single stock SSD, Sierra installed with latest updates.  I am trying to install High Sierra.

When I go to select the disk to install on (the current, normal boot volume), the installer refuses, with the error: `"This disk cannot be used to start your computer"`

Disk Utility First Aid can find nothing wrong.  The computer boots normally just fine with Sierra.

```
Volume name : Macintosh HD
Volume type : Logical Volume
BSD device node : disk1
Mount point : /
File system : Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)
Connection : PCI
Device tree path : IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/PEG2@1,2/SSD0@0/PRT0@0/PMP@0
Writable : Yes
Is case-sensitive : No
File system UUID : 308F1BD9-CF92-335C-B437-D47C941E7D76
CoreStorage UUID : 0E3E3C70-5FE7-484E-826B-828CDA8F3471
Parent CoreStorage LVG UUID : 13CB696B-1760-4072-A883-0ED19EFBEBF1
Volume capacity : 374,756,999,168
Available space (Purgeable + Free) : 168,884,392,284
Purgeable space : 9,433,788,764
Free space : 159,450,603,520
Used space : 205,872,606,884
File count : 1,735,041
Owners enabled : Yes
Is encrypted : Yes
System Integrity Protection supported : Yes
Can be verified : Yes
Can be repaired : No
Bootable : Yes
Journaled : Yes
Disk number : 1
Media name : Macintosh HD
Media type : Generic
Ejectable : No
Solid state : Yes
S.M.A.R.T. status : Not Supported
Parent disks : disk0s1
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I am however, dual booting Windows alongside MacOS. Are you too?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I've got dual boot too, iMac 2017 5K with fusion drive

Comment: @Fredefl I had a dual-boot linux partition, but I deleted it a while ago and added the space back to the mac disk.   So it appears the issue revolves around having multiple boot partitions (now or in the past).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have had the same issue. Spent time with Apple support but could not solve it. I too have a dual boot machine.

Answer (score 3):

You must turn off filevault before install HS...

Comment: While this may provide an answer to the question, it's good to provide supporting links/documentation explaining why your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess would be: remove rEFInd from the EFI or replace your current EFI partition (disk0s1) with a new one. Afterwards first backup and then remove any additional partition after disk0s3 (but not a recovery partition) and any second logical volume and finally expand the CoreStorage LVG to the full size of either 512 or 768 GB (depends on your SSD).

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem described here on my MacBookPro12,1 (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) running El Capitan, during attempts to upgrade to both High Sierra and Monterey.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58892/149185) led me to `gpt -r show disk0`, which reported output similar to the output reported [here](https://superuser.com/q/1140907/537463), including `Suspicious MBR at sector 0`, and `MBR` rather than `PMBR`.

The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1142088/537463) suggests using `gdisk` to replace the hybrid MBR with a legal protective MBR. Rather than installing `gdisk` on MacOS, I followed the advice in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1058425/435695) and used the Ubuntu `gdisk`.

All of this seems consistent with the comments following the question, which suggest that this problem is more likely with dual booting.

After the Ubuntu `gdisk` invocation, both Ubuntu and MacOS still booted successfully, and the Monterey installer accepted the MacOS partition as a target. Monterey is running now on that Mac, and Ubuntu still works also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing a full time machine backup, Booting recovery mode, bringing up diskutility there and reformating the disk.

Then did a restore from time machine.