# Dual boot: can no longer update to Mojave: "Disk cannot be used to start up"

Tags: software-update, mojave, dual-boot

I dual boot with Ubuntu. I have had no problem updating my system over the last 4 year (3 system updates).

I now need to update to Mojave and get the error message `This disk cannot be used to start up your computer.` when trying to update.

Would someone have a hint as to how I could do this without wiping out my Linux partition (as outlined in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299715/high-sierra-wont-install-for-the-boot-disk-it-says-this-disk-cannot-be-used))?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454773/149185) might be helpful. The upshot is that `gdisk` (which might already be installed in Ubuntu on your system) can replace a hybrid MBR with a protective MBR. It worked for me, for an upgrade to Monterey, with no need to wipe any partition.